# Convert latex to Word via pandoc with numbered and unnumbered sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, pandoc, msword, markdown

I have a document (`FromLaTeX.tex`) something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\subsection{Numbered subsection}
\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}
\section{Third}
\section*{References}
\end{document}
```

which I want to convert to Word using `pandoc`

```
pandoc -f latex -t docx -N --reference-doc=mycustomdoc.docx FromLaTeX.tex -o ToWord.docx
```

How can I suppress the numbering for `\section*`s in my Word document?

**Update/Clarification:**

I would like to use Word's built-in style-system for the headings and have created a `reference-doc` for `pandoc` to use (`mycustomdoc.docx`), which has numbered headings as the main heading-styles (Heading 1, Heading 2, etc.). I have also created unnumbered headings-styles that match the numbered ones in the same `reference-doc` (Unnumbered Heading 1, ...). I would like to be able to match the 
`\section*`s to these unnumbered headings when converting to `docx`.

Comment: First question i ask myself as a non-Word user: Does Word allow unnumbered sections?

Comment: @Johannes_B Word has a style system where you can define if you want your sections numbered or unnumbered. You can then define a set of numbered sections and a set of unnumbered sections. But I don't know how to tell `pandoc` to use one for `\section{}` and the other for `\section*{}`

Comment: `tex4ht` can convert your document with unnumbered sections. try `make4ht -f odt FromLaTeX.tex`.

Comment: @michal.h21 Hmm, that might be an option.  However, I would like to use `pandoc` since it's part of a more complex workflow using `pandoc-citeproc` and other things (omitted here for the MWE).  I tried your option though, but ... apologies for my ignorance ... where does the output go?

Comment: the output goes to `FromLaTeX.odt`, it can be converted to `docx` by LibreOffice. Word can open it as well, but the support isn't really good.

Comment: @michal.h21 I don't see any `FromLaTeX.odt` even if specifying the directory with `-d`. I do get an alert `/Library/TeX/texbin/make4ht:62: attempt to index local 'formatter' (a nil value)`?

Comment: @jan do you use TL 2018? there were some files missing when it was released, this can be fixed with update with `tlmgr update --all`

Comment: @michal.h21 Yes, on TL 2018, and yes updating it resolved it. Thanks much!  However, it's not quite what I'm looking for. In the `odt`-file the section numbers are basically written out instead of using styles (that Word and Open Office are capable of).  I'll update my question to clarify.